# Google Sign-in with any mail using GoogleSignInClient - Android

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

In my app, I want any user can login with their Google account.
When I'm using the same Gmail by which I have created an account on Google cloud it is working fine but whenever I'm trying to login  with any other account getting signInResult: failed code=**12500**

Here is my login code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .requestScopes(
            Scope(Scopes.PROFILE),
            Scope(Scopes.EMAIL),
            Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME),
            Scope(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE)
        )
        .build()
    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

    val account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)
    val isAlreadySignIn =
        account != null && GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, Scope(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE))

    if (!isAlreadySignIn) {
        sign_in_button.setOnClickListener {
            val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
        }
    } else {
        updateUI(account)
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        handleSignInResult(task)
    }
}

private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
    try {
        val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        updateUI(account)
    } catch (e: ApiException) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.w("TAG", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the 12500 error by adding a support mail in your project settings over at https://console.firebase.google.com/

Comment: I have already done this but still not working